# Как правильно пишется слово "брасс(-)квинтет"?

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, как пишутся слова "брасс-квартет/брассквартет" и "брасс-квинтет/брассквинтет"? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Оба слова через дефис пишутся.  Брасс-квинтет. Брасс- квартет. (Брасс- квинтет - это ансамбль, состоящий из пяти медных духовых инструментов,  брасс-квартет - из четырех).